# Event Hub processor- How to simulate closereason.shutdown in local dev box

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I copied the Event Hub sample code to my project for event processor:

```
  async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason);
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
    {
    await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

And I saw some exceptions thrown from await context.CheckpointAsync(); which invoked when reason == CloseReason.Shutdown.

How can I simulate this scenario in local debugging?

Comment: What exceptions? Can you post them?

Comment: Thanks Peter. It is leaselost exception. You can find details from my another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733546/about-microsoft-servicebus-messaging-leaselostexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the EventProcessorHost is running - invoke `eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync()`
- this will make sure `IEventProcessor.close()` is invoked with `CloseReason.Shutdown`.

See [this to understand EPH concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867611/3277385).